# user_id coming to be undefined in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement firebase cloud function in node.js to deploy in my project. i want to fetch the user id of the sending user inside the function but it is coming to be "undefined".

previously the "event" trigger was used to export the function but it has been migrated to v1.0.0 after beta version of firestore to "change, context" or "snap".

I am working on the latest query but can't get the user_id.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}").onWrite((change,context) => {

const user_id = context.user_id;
const notification_id = context.notification_id; 

return console.log("user_id: " + user_id);
```

This is returning me the "user_id: undefined" in the console. please can anyone tell me the correct way so that i get the user_id. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
const user_id = context.user_id;
const notification_id = context.notification_id;
```

into this:

```
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
```

> [`params`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#params)
>
> An object containing the values of the wildcards in the path parameter provided to the ref() method for a Realtime Database trigger.

Comment: this worked! . but can you tell me what is the use of the snap as well. i am unable to understand rhe documentation.

Comment: Where is there "snap"?

Comment: no i read the documentation. there also has a snap kind of thing. i don't know what is that used for.

Comment: oh yes `change` is used in `onWrite` and `onUpdate` since it has the `before` and `after` properties to retrieve data before the trigger and after the trigger. `onCreate` and `onDelete` uses `snap` since it is triggered only after data is created or deleted.

Comment: thank you for helping me out. stuck for the last few hrs to solve this issue. u saved my time.